# sql array does not work (background: nodejs with postgresql)

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

i'm newbie to nodejs and postgresql

background: nodejs api
database:postgresql

datatable: company_apps
column:status
as flow picture
http://take.ms/jqIpA

i want to get data with status in 'D' or 'P',like

```
select * from company_apps where status in ('D','P')
```

i try to use array to set filter,but it doesn't work. 
as flow picture
http://take.ms/dbpP7

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Massive, and `{$in: [value1, value2]}` is not the correct syntax -- Massive automatically generates `IN` clauses if the field value is an array, so you can just set `filter.status = ['D', 'P']`. There's more information in the [docs](http://massive-js.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

And please post code as code, not pictures.